# Write NSString as text label

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to write a string as text label. I have:

```
NSString *tempCompNum = [[retrievedArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] CompNumber];
sss_lbl.text = tempCompNum;
```

But this is not working..I mean I do not get anything in the label. Please help.

Comment: How did you create the label? Via Interface Builder? If yes, check if you connected everything right. If you did it via code, check if you added the label as a subview. ;-)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you stop with the debugger at the assignment "sss_lbl.text = tempCompNum" and make sure that "sss_lbl" is not nil and that "tempCompNum" contains the desired string? Have you made sure the label is indeed visible, e.g. by setting a fixed string in Interface Builder?

Comment: Just one thing, I am writing this in viewDidLoad. COuld that be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared the label as a property of the class?

```
IBOutlet UILabel *sss_lbl;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *sss_lbl;
```

Then in the m file...

```
@synthesize sss_lbl;
```

And made sure the connection is from the file's owner to the UILabel in question?

Comment: Also maybe try NSLog(@"%@", [[retrievedArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] CompNumber]); and see what's actually in the array.  If it's an integer change the %@ to %d or %.2f for float.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide a lot of information, but is it possible that you are missing one or more of the following lines?

```
sss_lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[view addSubview:sss_lbl];
```

By the way, sss_lbl is a terrible name.

Comment: the name is just an example here..Also the label is created in IB and I have connected the outlets.

Comment: Why not just call it label? More readable and easier to understand.